# How to find the xpath of element of a web page that located by it's class name | Java selenuim

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have a table on a web page that its xpath differs from time to time but its class name doesn't. so I can handle it by its class name but my code needs the xpath of that element so how to get the xpath of that element?
**OR** how to deal with such elements that its xpath differs from time to time?

```
    String xpath = "here sould be the xpath of that element";
    wait_page_loading(By.xpath(table_xpath)); //this other function in my class wait the page loading
    WebElement Webtable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table_xpath));
    List<WebElement> totalRowCount = Webtable.findElements(By.xpath(table_xpath + "/tbody/tr"));
    if(totalRowCount.size() <= 1) {
        throw new Exception("Can't find results in the problem page");
    }
    return totalRowCount.get(0).findElements(By.xpath("td")).get(6).getText();
```

*Thanks a lot in advance.*

Comment: Could you please show us the HTML code of the website?

Comment: @Kazi https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc205/submissions this page for example
And is wants to get the data of the table in it. i used xpath but I found that I differ from time to time wich cases errors

Comment: "//*[@id="main-container"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/table" 

This xpath should always be there. Could you please check and confirm?

Comment: @BlueFire : which element you are looking to extract  ?

Comment: @Kazi but sometimes it becomes "//*[@id="main-container"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/table" because the number of pages is not shown in some cases and in other cases there is another element at the top of the table wich changes its xpath. 
I tried to test every xpath but I am trying to find a more stable way than this

Comment: @cruisepandey the upper (first element) element of the column status

Comment: did not get which element is that ? can you upload a screenshot of the same ? not sure if this is the one `//div[@class='table-responsive']/table`

Comment: @cruisepandey this worked with me thanks alot. I was waiting to make your answer accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a div and then we have a child table, please use the below xpath :

```
//div[@class='table-responsive']/table
```

Answer (score 0):

Below `xPath` returns all the row values of the table.

```
//div[@class='table-responsive']/table/tbody/tr
```

> how to deal with such elements that its xpath differs from time to
> time?

If a `xPath` value partially dynamic I would suggest you to us `contains` method. For an example,

`<input class = "User1235">`

In above `xPath` the value 1235 is dynamic in this case you can create a `xPath` with `contains`

```
//input[contains(@class,'User')]
```